# How to combine feet and inches into one combined column

Tags: sql-server

Combining last name and first name isn't an issue for me - as shown above. The query spits that out fine. However, in this database schema, inches and feet are separated. When I try to combine them as height_feet + ' ' ' + height_inches, I get an error for obvious reasons. What's the best way to combine feet and inches, so that it reads as 6'7 for instance.

I've tried

```
,height_feet + ''' + height_inches as 'Height'
```

I've also tried

```
,concat(cast(height_feet as char), ''' ', cast(height_inches as char), '"')
```

Neither have helped me get the desired result. All I want is it to read 5'10 if feet is 5 and inches is 10.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    last_name + ', ' + first_name as 'Employee'
        ,days as 'Days Employed'
        ,height_feet
        ,height_inches
        ,ROUND(sales, 3) as 'Sales'
```

Comment: "However, in this database schema, inches and feet are separated." Can this poor design decision be changed?

Comment: I agree with ceejayoz. A single `height` column in inches would be simpler allowing indexed comparisons. Then use integer division and modulus to produce feet and inches. `select 61/12 as feet, 61%12 as inches;`.

Comment: Your question is tagged mysql, but the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: @Schwern FLOOR(61/12) !

Answer (score 1):

The right function to do concatenation in MySQL is [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), therefore use it for all your concatenations.

Your problem is just because you are trying to concatenate a reserved char `'`. In order to concatenate a single quote you need to escape it so you double it.

```
SELECT 
    concat(last_name, ', ', first_name) as 'Employee'
    ,days as 'Days Employed'
    ,concat(height_feet, '''',height_inches)
    ,ROUND(sales, 3) as 'Sales'
  from ...
 where ...
 LIMIT 10 -- "TOP 10" is MSSQL syntax
```

See an example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/102692

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you may have tagged your question with MySQL when it should be SQL SERVER. Nevertheless since SQL Server has the same function [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) the same query will work, see the same example running here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/54309

Comment: Despite the tag, I doubt that the OP is using MySQL